# alias becoming ineffective after some time in unix

Tags: unix, alias

I have added some alias in `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, as `~/.bashrc` file is not present in my Unix server. After that I executed the command `source /etc/skel/.bashrc` and I was able to use those alias.

But I noticed that after after few hours when I try to use the same alias, I am getting below error:

```
vm01:~ # rpmuninstall
-bash: rpmuninstall: command not found
```

Comment: It is rarely necessary to execute commands from a root prompt.  Login as a regular user and use `sudo` when you need elevated privileges.  Use functions instead of aliases, and put them in the startup script for the user.  Do not setup aliases or functions in the default shell of the root user: that is  just asking for trouble.

Comment: It probably means you are no longer in the same shell — for some reason or another.  Maybe you exec'd a shell; maybe you ran a new interactive non-login shell and the alias is still active in the parent shell (currently dormant) and not in the child shell.

Comment: @WilliamPursell...These alias I have created to install and uninstall rpm packages, which will create further create users and deploy binary files in unix machine and to do so, I have given access to root user.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler...everytime I am executing these alias from root user, although I am executing this in different sessions, like now I executed `source` command and used alias, and closed the session. After 5-6 hours I come up with new session (login as root always) and I am not able to use the same alias again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Aliases don't time out**. What probably happend is that you tried to run the alias in a different terminal (where you didn't source the skeleton) or logged out and in again.
2. **Adding personal aliases to `/etc/skel/.bashrc` is wrong**, since that
   file is used only as a skeleton when populating new user home
   directories. If you don't have a `$HOME/.bashrc`, create one by *copying*
   the skeleton and then add your aliases.